# Block cannot move

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to move this rectangle to make Pong. I had it working before but I messed up the code.
Could anyone help me make it move and possibly make my code look cleaner?

Again, I made it move, but the problem seems to be in the Update method.

Possibly the ScreenSide parameter???...

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen_width = 800
screen_height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
rectImg1 = 'Rect.jpg'
rectImg2 = 'Rect2.jpg'

RIGHT = "RIGHT"
LEFT = "LEFT"

WHITE = (255,255,255)
FPS = 30
PADDLE_SPEED = 5
BALL_SPEED = 10
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
xPos = 0
yPos = 0
leftY = 20
rightY = 20
class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screenSide):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.screenSide = screenSide
        if self.screenSide == LEFT:
            self.image = pygame.image.load(rectImg1).convert_alpha()
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.x = 20
            self.rect.y = 20
    def update(self):
        if self.screenSide == LEFT:
            self.y = leftY
allSpritesGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()

paddle = Paddle(LEFT)

allSpritesGroup.add(paddle)

#code to make it move
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    if paddle.screenSide == LEFT:
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                paddle.y += PADDLE_SPEED
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                paddle.y -= PADDLE_SPEED
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_s or event.key == pygame.K_w:
                 paddle.y == 0
    screen.fill((255,255,255))

    allSpritesGroup.draw(screen)
    allSpritesGroup.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please add details of what the code is doing and what is your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but your problem might be in:

```
elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pygame.K_s or event.key == pygame.K_w:
        paddle.y == 0
```

This looks more like a comparison and if not then you're setting the y to 0 whenever you let go of a key.

Also, You're right about the update function:

```
def update(self):
    if self.screenSide == LEFT:
        self.y = leftY
```

You're constantly setting the y to 20 so it won't move since every time it updates its moved to 20.

Answer (score 0):

Your event handling is broken. The `KEYDOWN` and `KEYUP` events are outside of the event loop because of this line `if paddle.screenSide == LEFT:`. You also need to update `paddle.rect.y` not `paddle.y` and you should do that in the class not with global variables. I'd give the paddles a `self.y_speed` attribute which you set in the event loop and then use it to update the `self.rect.y` position each frame in the `update` method. And remove the `screenSide` checks and just pass the image and position to the sprites during the instantiation.

```
import sys
import pygame


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

rectImg1 = pygame.Surface((30, 50))
rectImg1.fill((20, 20, 120))
rectImg2 = pygame.Surface((30, 50))
rectImg2.fill((120, 10, 20))

WHITE = (255,255,255)
FPS = 30
PADDLE_SPEED = 5
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, image, pos):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        self.y_speed = 0

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.y_speed


allSpritesGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()

paddle = Paddle(rectImg1, (20, 20))
paddle2 = Paddle(rectImg2, (750, 20))
allSpritesGroup.add(paddle, paddle2)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                paddle.y_speed = PADDLE_SPEED
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                paddle.y_speed = -PADDLE_SPEED
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_s or event.key == pygame.K_w:
                 paddle.y_speed = 0

    allSpritesGroup.update()

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    allSpritesGroup.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```